# BigInt(16795000205095893097) doesn't equal what expected

Tags: javascript, bigint

Why does this BigInt not equal `16795000205095893097`?

```js
const unsigned64bitPrime = BigInt(16795000205095893097)
console.log('unsigned64bitPrime = ', unsigned64bitPrime);

> "unsigned64bitPrime = " 16795000205095892992n
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integer literals are not BigInts, and so they can overflow. Use the "n" suffix to create BigInt literals. E.g.

```
const unsigned64bitPrime = 16795000205095893097n;
console.log('unsigned64bitPrime = ', unsigned64bitPrime);
```